# how to create animation of evolving graph (nodes and edges) in python

Tags: python, animation, networkx, pyvis

I have a graph with nodes and edges (not a plot) where the weights of the edges evolve over time. I'd like to create an animation of that.

I found that the main libraries for graphs in python are networkx and pyvis. I have not seen how to do what I want. For instance, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67307321/annimation-of-pyvis-graphs) question is asking the same but did not get an answer.

If it's not possible to do it directly, I was thinking of generating different html files and overlaying them to create an animation.

With this question I hope someone can share a way to generate that animation.

Comment: Do you truly need pyvis?  Because if not, there are plenty of SO threads about animating networkx plots directly with matplotlib.  Here are [the most popular appropriately tagged ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/networkx%2bmatplotlib%2banimation?tab=Frequent).

Comment: No. I was looking for those resources, but couldn't find them. Thanks for sharing.